# Using JSONP method for $http service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I'm a relative newbie to AngularJS, and having successfully used the GET method of $http for a basic proof-of-concept app, I'm now trying to use the JSONP method to pull some JSON from a remote URL I've been given. I've created a basic plunker here to show what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/Joud0ukAzhgvNM0h9KjB?p=preview

I'm using an HTTP request inside my controller like this:

```
    $http({method: 'jsonp', url: 'http://ec2-54-229-49-250.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/country?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'}).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
    console.log('success');
  }).
  error(function(data) {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

...but I'm getting nothing back at all (except 'error' in the console). I know the URL is returning valid JSON ( http://ec2-54-229-49-250.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/country?callback=angular.callbacks._0 ), but I'm just not getting anything back...

Comment: you could check the below url to check your function:   https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/orbitalofficial/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requires you to wrap your JSON response into a Javascript function call.
When you do a JSONP the request query string will set a parameter called 'callback' that will tell your server how to wrap the JSON response.

So the response should be something like:

```
callback([
    {"id": "1", "name": "John Doe"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Lorem ipsum"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "Lorem ipsum"}
]);
```

Angular will define the callback parameter as angular.callbacks._0, angular.callbacks._1, angular.callbacks._2 … depending on how many requests it is waiting for response, so if you do a single request the response should be:

```
angular.callbacks._0([
    {"id": "1", "name": "Lorem ipsum"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Lorem ipsum"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "Lorem ipsum"}
]);
```

The server should use the callback parameter from the request string to set the response accordingly.

Check your [Plunker's](http://plnkr.co/edit/Joud0ukAzhgvNM0h9KjB?p=preview) network activity and you will see that the request is setting the callback parameter but the response you are getting is not being wrapped with it.

[image]

Comment: Aah, I see - in that case I guess I'll need to see if the response can be amended to accommodate this. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way of getting this non-wrapped response inside the js application?

Comment: I don't think so, browsers implement [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and as far as I now JSONP is the only way to make cross domain requests.