# angularJS function in controller does not respond

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

### AngularJs ng-click does not respond

I'm trying to use the GitHub Search-API.
When someone click the button my Controller should call a search from github here is my code

HTML:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Controller/RepoController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="RepoController">
 <input type="text" ng-model="param" /><button ng-click="search()">suchen</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="repo in repos">
        {{repo.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
 
</body>
```

and here is my controller:

```
var App = angular.module('RepoSearch', []);
 
function RepoController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.repos = [];

    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='+$scope.param).success(function(data) {
            $scope.repos = data['items'];
        }
    }
 
}
```

but my repos-array is still empty
when I swap the `$http.get` with an alert it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `(` after `$scope.repos = data['items'];}`, and to define `ng-app`, which in this case, can be in `<head>` : `<head ng-app="RepoSearch">`
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

Comment: i defined  ng-app in my html tag but i couldnt handle to inster it into code section :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be cross domain call. Use JSONP to call into github.

```
$http.jsonp('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='+$scope.param+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'+).success(function(data) {
            $scope.repos = data['items'];
}
```

The callback method maybe different so look at these SO posts

[Using angularjs JSONP when callback cant be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375033/using-angularjs-jsonp-when-callback-cant-be-defined)

[Using JSONP method for $http service in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062450/using-jsonp-method-for-http-service-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<head ng-app="RepoSearch">
      <script src="js/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/Controller/RepoController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="RepoController">
     <input type="text" ng-model="param" /><button ng-click="search()">suchen</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="repo in repos">
            {{repo.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>

    </body>
```

in Controller

```
var App = angular.module('RepoSearch', []);


//bind controller with your app

App.controller('RepoController',RepoController);

function RepoController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.repos = [];

    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='+$scope.param).success(function(data) {
            $scope.repos = data['items'];
        }
    }

}
```