# HTTP JSONP request issue with $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, jsonp

I get the bellow error when I try to use the `JSONP` method in angularJS.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    http://example.com/getSomeJson?format=jsonp&json_callback=angular.callbacks._0

What am I doing wrong here, this is my AngularJs controller with the http request:

### UPDATED QUESTION DETAILS

See below with code snipit which reproduces my problem, I've commented some of the `.js` to illustrate what I've tried so far.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.controller('mainController', ['$http', 'mainService', function($http, mainService){

 mainCtrl = this;

 mainCtrl.test = "If you can see this the mainController works"

 var promise = mainService.getJson();
 promise.then(function (data)
 {
  mainCtrl.json = data;
 });
}]);

app.service("mainService", function ($http, $q)
{
  var deferred = $q.defer();
 
    /*  
    // Method to Grab JSON that has CORs enabled:
    // JSON resource with CORs enabled
 var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
 $http({
     method: 'GET',
     cache: true,
     url: url,
           headers: {  
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'  
       }
 }).
 success(function(response) {
     //your code when success
     deferred.resolve(response);
     console.log('HTTP CORS SUCCESS!');
 }).
 error(function(response) {
     //your code when fails
     console.log('HTTP CORS ERROR!');
 });
*/ 


 /* */
    // Method to Grab JSON that has CORs enabled:
 // JSON resources without CORs enabled
 var url = 'http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-1.json' // does not work?
    // var url = 'http://samcroft.co.uk/json-data/sample'  // this one works

 $http({
        method: 'jsonp',
        url: url + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    }).
 success(function(response) {
     //your code when success
     deferred.resolve(response);
     console.log('JSONP SUCCESS!');
 }).
 error(function(response) {
     //your code when fails
     console.log('JSONP ERROR!');
 });


 
 this.getJson = function ()
 {
  return deferred.promise;
 };


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
 <p>{{mainCtrl.test}}</p>
 <hr />
 <p>You should also see the JSON obeject below:</p>
 {{mainCtrl.json}}
</body>
</html>
```

### ORIGIONAL QUESTION DETAILS

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    var url = 'http://example.com/getSomeJson';

    $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: url,
        params: {
            format: 'jsonp',
            json_callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    }).
    success(function(data) {
        //your code when success
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
    }).
    error(function(status) {
        //your code when fails
        console.log('ERROR!');
    });
}]);
```

When I look at the json in the chromes sources panel I see where the error is highlighted.
[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Or could it be an issue with how the API service is configured?

Comment: `json_callback` needs to just be `callback`

Comment: @Ronnie `callback` didn't work :(

Comment: same error message? What version of angular are you using?

Comment: @ronnie I'm using  v1.5.9

Comment: what does your jsonp look like?

Comment: are you getting back json or jsonp? In order to use jsonp your json has to be wrapped in a function. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062450/using-jsonp-method-for-http-service-in-angularjs without that, you get the error you are describing `unexpected token :`

Comment: @Ronnie, do you know how it has to be wrapped in a function, I tried that by setting the `json_callback` param.  I also tried just `callback`

Comment: @Holy You can check my below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :-)

The code you tried with the `jsonp` request looks good but the url you used is not supporting the `jsonp` request, that's why you got an error.

If you try the same url with `$http.get`, it will work fine.

To support the `jsonp` call, the response should be wrapped with the `JSON_CALLBACK ()` as below

```
JSON_CALLBACK ({ /* JSON */ })
```

Hence, I changed this to valid `jsonp` url and it worked!

https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

You can try this url in the browser and see the response, how it is wrapped with `JSON_CALLBACK ()`.

But if you try the below url, you can just see the `json` without any wrapping.

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-1.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

That's the difference to find whether the api supports `jsonp`.

Also, I have changed the `service` below with the same syntax as in another `SO` question answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41030976/7055233

**Working snippet**:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.controller('mainController', ['$http', 'mainService', function($http, mainService){

 mainCtrl = this;

 mainCtrl.test = "If you can see this the mainController works"

 var promise = mainService.getJson();
 promise.then(function (data)
 {
  mainCtrl.json = data;
 });
}]);

app.service("mainService", function ($http, $q)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();
 var url = 'https://angularjs.org/greet.php';
 //var url = 'http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/v8xyYN64V4nqCshgjKms/data-1.json';
 
    /*  
    // Method to Grab JSON that has CORs enabled:
    // JSON resource with CORs enabled
 var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
 $http({
     method: 'GET',
     cache: true,
     url: url,
           headers: {  
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'  
       }
 }).
 success(function(response) {
     //your code when success
     deferred.resolve(response);
     console.log('HTTP CORS SUCCESS!');
 }).
 error(function(response) {
     //your code when fails
     console.log('HTTP CORS ERROR!');
 });
*/ 


 /* */
    // Method to Grab JSON that has CORs enabled:
 // JSON resource without CORs enabled
  function getJson() {

 // $http.jsonp(url + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").  // this does not work either
 $http.jsonp(url + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
 then(function(response) {
     //your code when success
     deferred.resolve(response);
     console.log('JSONP SUCCESS!');
 }, function(response) {
     //your code when fails
     console.log('JSONP ERROR!');
        deferred.reject(response);
 });
 
    return deferred.promise;

  }
 
 this.getJson = getJson;


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.js"></script>
 <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
 <p>{{mainCtrl.test}}</p>
 <hr />
 <p>You should also see the JSON obeject below:</p>
 {{mainCtrl.json}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks man, I didn't realise the API has to support JSONP.  What's the advantage over using CORS vs JSONP, is it just what whoever is using providing the API decides to go with?

Comment: If the api is in your own server with different domain name, then you can explictly give access to your another domain with the `access-control` header and you can access it with `cors`. If a thrird party domain is not supporting `cors` but allows `jsonp` request, then you access it through `jsonp`. `cors` has much power as you can control which http method can be given access like `post` or `delete` etc. But `jsonp` is similar to `get`.

Comment: Thanks, really good to know thatI can check if JSONP is supported by going to the URL with `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` appended.  One last question if I may, would you use an AngularJS Service, Factory, or Provider to get JSON data like this?  Or is it much of a muchness for all I'm trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15666048/1814446

Comment: There are few differences between them as in the link and I would recommend to go with the `factory` in your above case rather than the `service`. I will give a different link later to understand them better.

Answer (score 0):

### [JSONP callback must be specified by `jsonpCallbackParam`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fb663418710736161a6b5da49c345e92edf58dcb)

> BREAKING CHANGE
>
> You can no longer use the `JSON_CALLBACK` placeholder in your JSONP requests.
>   Instead you must provide the name of the query parameter that will pass the callback via the `jsonpCallbackParam` property of the config object, or app-wide via the `$http.defaults.jsonpCallbackParam` property, which is `"callback"` by default.

-- Added to **AngularJS v1.6.0-rc.2**

---

### UPDATE

The OPs example code does not work because the `http://run.plnkr.co` API does not support JSONP.

JSONP is available only on some sites with an API that pre-date [ACCESS-CONTROL headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

For more information, see [JSONP Demystified](https://sacha.me/articles/jsonp-demystified/)

Comment: thanks but that didn't work but we're using v1.5.9.  I tried both `json_callback: 'jsonpCallbackParam'` and `callback: 'jsonpCallbackParam'`

Comment: I updated my question with a code snippet which reproduces the issue