# What's the best way to pass "$routeParams" to a Service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

In my angularJs app I'm able to get $routeParams  in the controller but how should I get it in a service?  I would like to follow the separation of concerns approach and keep my http requests separate from my controllers.

I've tried the below in my `app.js` but I get a `Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider`

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);  // TODO: 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap' 

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/static/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController as mainCtrl'

        })
        .when('/match/id-:matchId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/match/matchView.html',
            controller: 'matchController as matchCtrl'
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('matchController', ['$routeParams', 'matchService', function ($routeParams, matchService) {
    var matchCtrl = this;
    matchCtrl.matchId = $routeParams..matchId;  // how can I move this into the service

    this.getMatchId = function ()
    {
        return matchCtrl.matchId;
    };

    var promise = matchService.getMatch();
    promise.then(function (data)
    {
        matchCtrl.match = data;
    });
}])

app.service("matchService", function ($http, $q, matchController)
{
    var matchId = matchController.getTable();

    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        url: url,
        headers: {  
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'  
        }
    }).
    success(function(response) {
        //your code when success
        // lgTblCtrl.amateurTable = data;
        deferred.resolve(response);
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
    }).
    error(function(response) {
        //your code when fails
        console.log('ERROR!');
    });

    this.getTable = function ()
    {
        return deferred.promise;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have created **cyclic reference** where the `matchService` is injected into the `matchController` and `matchController` is injected into the `matchService`.

Service is a **singleton** object, created once which is the same instance passed wherever it gets injected. On contrast, controller will be created one per view. So if you have two views using the same controller, separate controller instances will be created and used by them by not sharing the $scope. So, if you inject a controller to the service, again another instance will be created and injected to the service.

Since a service should be generic and independent of the controller, you should not inject controller to any service as per the best coding practice.

Also, as a service is *singleton* and can be used by any controller or view, it should be independent to the view/route and hence you can't use `$routeParams` inside the service.

Instead, you can pass the `$routeParams.matchId` as an argument to the service method.

**Note**: In your controller, you have used `$routeParams..matchId` with `double dots (..)` instead of `$routeParams.matchId`.

Also, there is no `matchService.getMatch` inside the `matchService` which used by the controller.

You have to correct them.

I have changed the code below as I explained and have a look.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);  // TODO: 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap' 

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/app/static/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController as mainCtrl'

        })
        .when('/match/id-:matchId', {
            templateUrl: '/app/components/match/matchView.html',
            controller: 'matchController as matchCtrl'
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('matchController', ['$routeParams', 'matchService', function ($routeParams, matchService) {
    var matchCtrl = {};

    var promise = matchService.getMatch($routeParams.matchId);
    promise.then(function (data)
    {
        matchCtrl.match = data;
    });
}])

app.service("matchService", function ($http, $q)
{
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    function getMatch(matchId) {
      var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        url: url,
        headers: {  
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'  
        }
      }).
      then(function(response) {
        //your code when success
        // lgTblCtrl.amateurTable = data;
        deferred.resolve(response);
        console.log('SUCCESS!');
      }, function(response) {
        //your code when fails
        console.log('ERROR!');
        deferred.reject(response);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    this.getMatch = getMatch;
})
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense but I still can't get it working with what you put above.  There are no errors in the console, but when I put breakpoints in the Chrome Source panel  I see it breaks on `this.getMatch = getMatch` before any of the `promise` or `deferred` statements.  When it breaks on `deferred.resolve(response);` I can see the data in the `response` but it doesn't get passed in `matchCtrl.match = data`

Comment: I will create a sample app and look at it shortly.

Comment: I got it working with https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c8eeec87d3b40bdbcae7c640a82ab81, What do you think, it seems to be working well.  If you add/include it in your answer I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: yeah that's correct. This was `return deferred.promise` missed out. I have updated the answer. Thanks for letting me know :-)

Comment: if you have time to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41025101/1814446 I'd really appreciate it.  I would owe you a beer!